# How to install Sharepoint 2013, AD and SQL Database separately

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, installation, virtual-machine, sql-server-2012

I have a ISO with SharePoint 2013 Standard Edition and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and want to make a  SharePoint environment with Active Directory on 3 virtual Machines (using Hyper-V).

Instead of install your SharePoint on your SQL server, as usual, I want to install everything separate. This means the Sharepoint 2013 on a own machine, MS SQL 2012 on a own machine and Active Directory on a own machine.

All machines are connected in a virtual LAN which allow them tho access together and to communicate.

**My question is: How to do that? What are the steps to get a successful result**

1. Does every machine has to have the same Operation System?
2. Should I first make a lan connection between the machines before I start to install the Server applications?
3. How to config the connection/ access between them?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Active Directory for your accounts, then yes, you need to configure your machines on a virtual LAN and [create an Active Directory domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574166.aspx). This is not a simple process and isn't really on topic for this site. You should be able to find tutorials on this process pretty easily using Google.

> 1. Does every machine has to have the same Operation System?

No, the server running Active Directory can be any version of Windows that can act as a domain controller. The other servers need to meet the requirements of the specific applications.

> 2. Should I first make a lan connetion between the machines before I start to install the Server applications?

Yes, all of the machines should be networked together and joined to the Active Directory domain before you install SQL Server and SharePoint.

> How to config the connection/ access between them?

This is not really on topic for this site and [it depends on the virtualization system that you are using](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XawQrbRzow0). If you have questions about how to configure networking in a virtual environment in Hyper-V you might want to try [Super User StackExchange](https://superuser.com/).